# Perl regex for char '&'

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string to match such that one of them is 'Tom & Jerry' and other is 'M&M chocolates'. I have tried the following regex but it does not match up the char '&'in either case

```
if($word =~ m/\w+\s&\s\w+/ or $word =~ m/\w\W\w\s\w+/)
```

Please can somebody help me over here. Thank you.

Comment: Escape it using backslash?

Comment: Not working. Any other suggestion.

Comment: well, the regex seems ok, not a perl expert myself.. but seems ok-ish. What if you remove the or part of the condition?

Comment: You can test the regex here: https://www.debuggex.com/r/ENdQZsmnU-XRawyv

Comment: Any reason for downgrade?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think it's because the question is rather poor. "Does not match &" -- how did you come to that conclusion? BTW, `\w+\s?&\s?\w+` matches both "Tom & Jerry" and "M&M".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be an error somewhere else in your program.

This works as expected:

```
$s1 = 'M&M chocolates';
$s2 = 'Tom & Jerry';
printf("$s1\n") if $s1 =~ m/\w\W\w\s\w+/;
printf("$s2\n") if $s2 =~ m/\w+\s&\s\w+/;
```

outputs

```
M&M chocolates
Tom & Jerry
```